# Python web.py HTTP/1.1 GET /" -404 Not Found

Tags: python, web

I'm learning python with book "Learn python the hard way"
I'm doing the web exercise, but I can't find a concrete information.

```
import web

urls =( '/hello', 'Index')
app = web.application(urls,globals())
render = web.template.render(<mypath>)

class Index(object):

def GET(self):
   return render.hello_form()

def POST(self):
    form  = web.input(name="Nobody", greet="Hello")
    greeting = "%s, %s" %(form.greet, form.name)
    return render.index(greeting = greeting)
```

then... in my "hello_form"

```
<form action="/hello" method="POST">
A greeting <input type=text" name="greet">
<br/>
Your Name:  <input type="text" name="name">
<br/>
<input type="submit>
</form>
```

well, **I can't access to the action="/hello".**

**but I can access with action="/"** well I don't know which is the reason

Someone could explain me?

Answer (score 1):

when you run you app.py bu default you are directed here:

http://0.0.0.0:8080/

But it says to you "File Not Found" because you have to go here:

http://0.0.0.0:8080/hello

So either you change your app.py keeping only / in your urls 
either you add manually /hello in your URL.

Cheers,

Filiberto